# Any way to encrypt Google Apps Script code?

Tags: encryption, google-apps-script

I need to know if it is currently possible to encrypt / hide the code of a web application that our team developed in G.A.S. . Is important because we need that customers may not have access to the code, and copy it.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Google Apps Script runs on a server not on your browser.

Comment: Whose account will the Apps Script file be on?  If the Apps Script file is in the customers Google Drive, then you can't protect it.  A library is just one Apps Script file referencing another Apps Script file.  You can add an Apps Script library which you own to an Apps Script file that they own, which will hide the code, but it won't guarantee that your code will be protected.  If you can make the code an add-on to a document, like a spreadsheet, then you could protect the code.

Answer (score 0):

for hide, Save critical function code as library

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/libraries